# Unable to select an option from drop down as i have 2 drop down with the same '<select class=

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Am unable to select options from the drop down.

```html
<span id="0d0a94458b224913b9db5e62081831f5" class="sf-element sf-element-control sfc-property sfc-dropdown" style="color: Black; font-family: "Arial"; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; display: inline-block;">
<div class="sf-element sf-element-dropdown" style="position: relative; width: 65px;" title="">
<div class="sf-element sf-element-icon" style="position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 55px; height: 18px; width: 18px;">
<svg width="18px" height="18px">
</div>
<div class="sf-element sf-element-text-box" style="display: inline-block; word-wrap: break-word; width: 47px;">2013/10</div>
<select class="sf-dropdown-select" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: "Arial";">
<option value="0">2010/01</option>
<option value="1">2010/02</option>
<option value="2">2010/03</option>
<option value="3">2010/04</option>
<option value="4">2010/05</option>
<option value="5">2010/06</option>
```

As i have one more drop down with the same

so how to differentiate and get the options selected in drop down box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two `select` box you should try with below `xPath`

1- for **first** `select` :-

```
"(//select[contains(@class, 'sf-dropdown-select')])[1]"
```

2-  for **last** `select` :-

```
"(//select[contains(@class, 'sf-dropdown-select')])[last()]"
```

**Note** :- You can change **indexing** based on your chioce.

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: thank you saurab.. it works fine for multi select box